# How do the drag coefficient and the Reynolds number relate to one another? (Mathematically speaking)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, viscosity

Could someone please explain me how to derive the mathematical relationship between the two?

Comment: If you look at the wikipedia pages, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number you will see it depends on the physical conditions, airfoils, pipes, flat plates, you name it.....I mean that literally , what object have you got in mind? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: @CountTo10 Suppose you have an object travelling in a fluid (for example an object in free fall in the atmosphere) how could I relate the drag coefficient to the reynolds in that case?

Answer (score 1):

I was a drilling fluid engineer many decades ago and we then calculated by hand daily the pressure drop through our drill bits, equivelant circulating densities Etc.. Oh the good old days,  Try the link [www.drillinghandbook.com/category/engineering-calculations](http://www.drillinghandbook.com/category/engineering-calculations)                    Mostly under the section drilling pressure losses.  This might help.